# Undo local change and force checkout from remote a file that requires merging

Tags: git

I `stash`ed my local changes in order to sync up with the remote.  After `pull`ing, I proceeded to `pop` the stash:

```
>git stash pop
Auto-merging somedir/someFile.xyz
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in somedir/someFile.xyz
```

Say I realized that I want to discard all the changes to `somedir/someFile.xyz` and simply bring in the version from the remote.  I tried

```
>git checkout somedir/someFile.xyz
error: path 'somedir/someFile.xyz' is unmerged
```

How do I undo my local changes and force checkout from remote a file that shows as requiring a merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use some switches which git provides like :

```
git checkout --ours somedir/someFile.xyz
```

or

```
git checkout --theirs somedir/someFile.xyz
```

As far as I remember the `--ours` switch will bring you file version from the `HEAD` in contradict `--theirs` switch will apply changes from your stash in file which you typed.

Comment: `--theirs` worked I was able to get the file checked out.  however, when I did a `git status`, the file remained shown as needing merge.  how do i get it out of that state altogether?

Comment: In order to do proper merge you must first resolve all merge conflicts around all files, and then you should type sth like `git add somedir/someFile.xyz` or apply patches you want to through `git add --interactive` after this you should be able to continue with `git commit`

Answer (score 0):

Use the force option when checking it out.

From `git --help checkout`-

> -f, --force   When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs   from HEAD. This is used to throw away local
>   changes.
>
> When checking out paths from the index, do not fail upon unmerged
>   entries;   instead, unmerged entries are ignored.

So, `git checkout -f <remote> somedir/someFile.xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `git merge --abort`, it abort a merge it might also work with a conflict arising from `git stash pop`, I'm not sure though.